# How can I eliminate these nested Promises?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I've read that you should **avoid nested promises** in JavaScript, as they tend to be an antipattern, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to avoid them in my particular use case.  Hopefully someone with more experience than me can see where I'm going wrong? Any advice would be much appreciated!!

Essentially, I'm retrieving some data asynchronously, processing it and catching a possible Error, and then saving some data asynchronously.  Here's a much-simplified example:

```
class Foo {
  changeName(path, newName) {
      this.getPage(path) // AJAX call, returns a promise with type Page,
                         //  may throw an Error if the page does not exist.
        .then(page=> {
          // Some modifications are made to page, omitted here
          return page
        })
        .catch(e=>{
          if(e instanceof PageDoesNotExistError) {
            return new Page();
          }
        })
        .then(page=> {
          page.name = newName;
          this.savePage(path, page); // ******
          // I want my outer changeName method to return this ^ promise,
          // or at least a promise that will resolve when this promise
          // resolves, with the same value.
        })
  }
}
```

How can I have `changeName` return a promise that will resolve with the value of `this.savePage` (the line marked with `//******`), so that I could do something like this elsewhere:

```
myFooInstance.changeName('/path', 'New Name').then(page=> {
  // Do something with the returned saved page
});
```

Comment: Uh, just `return` it? Notice that there isn't any nesting yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I have changeName return a promise that will resolve with the value of this.savePage

Return the promise `savePage` returns from the `then` handler. That will resolve the promise created by `then` to the promise from `savePage`, meaning that the promise created by `then` will be fulfilled or rejected depending on what the promise from `savePage` does. *(Details on that terminology in [my blog post here](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/02/08/lets-talk-about-how-to-talk-about-promises/) if you're interested.)*

```
.then(page=> {
    page.name = newName;
    return this.savePage(path, page);
})
```

Separately, you've said you want the caller to be able to use the promise on the return value of `changePage` but you're not returning anything out of `changePage`. You need to add `return` in front of the whole structure so you return the ultimate promise.

```
changeName(path, newName) {
    return this.getPage(path) // AJAX call, returns a promise with type Page,
    // ...
```

*(See below for a complete version.)*

---

Side note: You have an error waiting to happen here:

```
.catch(e=>{
    if(e instanceof PageDoesNotExistError) {
        return new Page();
    }
})
```

If `e` is not an instance of `PageDoesNotExistError`, you're converting the rejection into a resolution with the value `undefined`, because your `catch` handler doesn't return an explicit value in that case. If you want to propagate the error instead, you need to do that with `throw e` or `return Promise.reject(e)`:

```
.catch(e=>{
    if(e instanceof PageDoesNotExistError) {
        return new Page();
    }
    return Promise.reject(e);
})
```

---

Bringing all three of those things together:

```
class Foo {
    changeName(path, newName) {
        return this.getPage(path)
            .then(page=> {
                // Some modifications are made to page, omitted here
                return page;
            })
            .catch(e=>{
                if(e instanceof PageDoesNotExistError) {
                    return new Page();
                }
                return Promise.reject(e);
            })
            .then(page=> {
                page.name = newName;
                return this.savePage(path, page);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: @jfriend00: I'm weak on my promise dupes. Do you have one handy covering this that I can add to my list?

Comment: thank you for covering the single-branch `if` statement. so many devs miss this

Comment: problem fixed `if` javascript eliminates single-branch conditionals `else` persist deadly pitfall ^_^

Comment: Thanks so much! This was much simpler than I expected!

Answer (score 0):

You would just return the promise and in turn return from any nested promise:

```
class Foo {
  changeName(path, newName) {
      return this.getPage(path)
        .catch(e => {
          if(e instanceof PageDoesNotExistError) {
            return new Page();
          }
        })
        .then(page=> {
          page.name = newName;

          return this.savePage(path, page); // assuming that this is a promise
        })
  }
}
```

Comment: even if `this.savePage` is not a promise, it wouldn't matter. `Promise.then` automatically promotes a non-Promise return value to a Promise.